# Detecting whether cookies are enabled through IWebBrowser2 Interface

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

Is it possible to detect whether cookies are enabled in Internet Explorer through the [IWebBrowser2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28VS.85%29.aspx) or through some other [WebBrowser Control C/C++ interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752042%28VS.85%29.aspx)?  I can't see any obvious way to do it, but was wondering whether there is a subtle way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the URL to [InternetGetPerSiteCookieDecision()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537332(VS.85).aspx) and it should tell you what the policy is for that site.

It is a pretty terribly named API.  :-/

Comment: But accepting cookies is a local setting in your browser.  You can either accept, block, or prompt for both first-party cookies and third-party cookies.  I don't see how this is dependent on particular sites.

Comment: Yes, but you can also override it on a per-site bases (Tools -> Internet Options -> Privacy -> Sites (in IE8)).  This API will take all of the above into account.